# Why isn't the state of a transition maintained once it ends?

Tags: vue.js

I wanted to slightly expand the [basic example for transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components) and have an element fading out in one `div` and at the same time fading in on another:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 2s
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-show="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-show="!show">hello</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

This does not however work as intended: the upper `hello` fades out and the lower one fades in (so far OK), but then the lower one dissapears and the upper one appears (immediately, as if the state have changed and there were no transitions).

When clicking the button once again, it looks like the transition is correct (it starts with the lower `hello` fading out and the upper one fading in).

The CSS is symmetrical, the state changes only when pressing the button - so I do not understand the immediate switch after the first transition?

Comment: The second one does not disappear - it just jumps up to the top, when first element's opacity = 0 (the first element completely disappears and its space become vacant). Make diverse text in divs to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-show` hides elements by settings the `display` CSS property as explained by [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show):

> `v-show` simply toggles the `display` CSS property of the element.

This has the effect that the element disappears after the transition completes, which is when the `display` property is set. Elements with `display: none` are completely hidden without any space occupied for the element.

The effect you see is not symmetrical because when hiding the element, the display property is set when the transition ends, but when showing the element again, it needs to be set when the transition starts (otherwise the transition would be invisible).

If you want to avoid that position change, you will have to keep the element in the calculated layout all the time, so you cannot use `display: none` to hide it but have to use a different way. This also means that you cannot use `v-show` for this.

What you could do is simply use CSS transitions and transition between different `opacity` states:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
.fading-element {
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
.invisible {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">Toggle</button>
  <p :class="['fading-element', { 'invisible': !show }]">hello</p>
  <p :class="['fading-element', { 'invisible': show }]">hello</p>
</div>
```